# How to parse a CSV line in java

Tags: java, maven, csv

I am having different use case than just using a csv reader and providing it with a CSV file for parsing. I need a java library for which I can provide a line from a CSV file and it should be able to parse it.

Any java libraries available which can do that ? (I tried google'ing for a while before posting this.). I found opencsv from apache, in its java docs it says it has a API called CSVParser which takes a line and parses it, but that API doesn't really exist in the binaries.

I am trying this dependency

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId> 
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId> 
    <version>2.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

and try initializing CSVParser. Its doesn't work. I am not sure there is a different or new version of opencsv, which I am missing, please let me know

Comment: You must've missed something. OpenCSV works perfectly

Comment: I found 5 other Java CSV parser libraries in a couple of minutes looking ...

Comment: What exactly is it that doesn't work? Can you provide more information? E.g. can you provide the failing code, the compilation errors, the Maven error messages, etc?

Comment: This import doesnt work. import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser; with the dependency I have, but I am not able to find new versions.

Comment: @voldemort This question does not contain enough detail in its current form to answer. Try to edit your question and add more relevant info, like error messages, your current code, what you've tried, what "isn't working", etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, read it over. If you improve your question, it may be reopened, or you can ask a new one (you really could just edit this one). If you do edit, reply to this comment with `@Chris` and I'll come vote to reopen if it is better.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't really exist". [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) works perfectly. A usage example from the official website:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

Note, that `CSVReader` wraps `CSVParser` which is more low-level. The above example should be sufficient for any regular use, though.

Comment: Try this maven dependency <dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
 <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
 <version>2.0</version>
</dependency> and try initializing CSVParser. Its doesn't work. I am not sure there is a different or new version of opencsv, which I am missing, please let me know

Comment: @voldemort: You should add those details to the question. With those details, the problem may appear more relevant than it is now...